# How to get Current and Previous Year details in report

Tags: reporting, business-objects

Hi i am facing a problem where in report level i will give prompt for year 
based on prompt result i should get previous year details also 
Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

first of all dublicate the query. For the second query, you must create two variables in the universe level. Both of these variables will capture the prompt values and do the year subtraction. Now back to second query , instead of prompts , you should use these previously created variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create/modify the query yourself, you can play with date arithmetic, some examples in SQL Server can be found here: http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/34594, if you don't use SQL Server, you can look for the especific functions of your database by googling "date arithmetic [Your Database]".